# How to catch Javascript exceptions of type?

Tags: javascript, oop, exception

I wonder how can I implement Javascript exception of type. Let's suppose that I have a Javascript class, for example `MyCustomException` and I would like to have a try-catch where the catch would specify that I want to catch any exception thrown that is an instance of `MyCustomException` or a subclass.

This is a sample Javascript try-catch:

```
try {
  nonExistentFunction();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  // Expected output: ReferenceError: nonExistentFunction is not defined
  // (Note: the exact output may be browser-dependent)
}
```

This is a sample PHP try-catch (PHP is just an illustration, this question is not about PHP):

```
<?php

class MyException extends Exception { }

class MyOtherException extends Exception { }

class Test {
    public function testing() {
        try {
            throw new MyException();
        } catch (MyException | MyOtherException $e) {
            var_dump(get_class($e));
        }
    }
}

$foo = new Test;
$foo->testing();
```

In this latter example I can tell PHP to catch **any** `MyException` or `MyOtherException`, even if the exception is a subclass of any of them. Is this possible in Javascript?

Comment: You need `instanceof` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: @SyndRain no. My question refers to types and subtypes.

Comment: @NgDaddy yes, I am aware of `instanceof`, but I wonder about subtypes as well. I would like to catch(SomeException e) where e could be either an instance of SomeException or some class that inherits it.

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm afraid JS is helpless for your needs :(

Comment: @NgDaddy I have asked this question because the other day a colleague asked me about it and I already have an idea about this. So if there are no answers or the answers are not as good as I would like, then I will (try to) write one myself. Back then I told my coleague the basic building blocks I would use. But I'm not 100% that it would work properly.

Comment: `instanceof SomeException` is true for subclasses of `SomeException`.

Comment: `instanceof` checks the instance's prototype chain.

Comment: Unfortunately, JS doesn't have built-in syntax to catch specific exception classes, like PHP and Python do. You have to write your own `instanceOf` checks.

Comment: @Barmar you are correct: https://jsfiddle.net/6rbqy98o/. Closing the question.

Comment: @LajosArpad ... a possible error type detection ... `function getErrorType(value) { return (/\[object\s+Error\]/).test(Object.prototype.toString.call(value)) && Object.getPrototypeOf(value)?.name || null; }`